Toyota 4runner 1998 AT 5vz fe 143000km
After got my injectors changed to correct misfiring condition, I am now running lean and cannot find the trouble since 2 weeks now.
My OSB1S1 fluctuate between .6 and .3 V and my OSB1S2 is steady at 0.2V (lean)
My concerns are at idling: STFT=+18% and LTFT=+39% . ECM try to add fuel and it does not seems to get in cylinders taking into account FP=40lb and injectors are new.
Sometime STFT=LTFT=39%.  Why my STFT does not get down after my LTFT had gone so high ?
If i drive like this I get a P0171 lean code. Increase rpm get my LTFT down momentary.
OSB1, MAF, injectors and PCV got changed.Fuel rail at 40lb, No intake or exhaust leaks
Could my intake valves be defective ?
Anyone could help ? It is over my knowledge
thank you
Jean

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did you try resetting the ECM, thus forcing it to relearn the fueling trims? The two O2's you are showing data for are the upstream (OSB1S1 ... shouldn't that be O2B1S1) and downstream (OSB1S2). Downstream should be steady state. This shows the health of the cat. If ECM is not showing a P0420, I don't think I'd worry about it. How do either of these differ from the corresponding Bank 2 O2 sensors?

Thank you Yes I did reset ECM  by getting it disconnected for at leat 30 mins  and another time by shorting positive and negative cable for 5 mins at least without any change exept thqat it took long time before getting into close loop.
